# tls: bad certificate after certificate updates

Tags: certificate, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have `Hyperledger Fabric` (1.3) network which had expired certificates.
I was not able to execute peer chaincode commands.

I have generated certificates using same ca server and replaced. Now I am able to run `query` commands but still getting following error on peer for `invoke`,

```
2022-11-23 15:07:01.440 UTC [grpc] createTransport -> DEBU 0be grpc:
addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer1:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: 
desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: bad certificate". Reconnecting...
```

Kindly help. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What certs expired? Just peer certs or both peer and orderer certs? peer MSP sign certs or admin sign certs or tls certs

Comment: if the admin sign cert expired too, you need to fetch the channel config and replace the old expired in it with the new certs.

Comment: yes you are right, chaincode upgrade is channel operation and for that we need update channel config also. Replacing certs only make transactions working.

Comment: Fabric v2.x remove it from channel config. Its easier to renew certs of peers and orderers